# Azure pipelines, Docker push to Nexus Repository Manager

Tags: docker, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, nexus, azure-pipelines-yaml

I have a repo with a simple docker file. I build it using the `docker@2` task and would like to store the image on the nexus repository.
I created a service connection to the nexus repository manager as a Docker Registry and provided the credentials( URL : https://nexus.XX.de, name:DockerTest)

When I try to push it to the nexus repo, I fail. I get an error saying :

```
Starting: Push the image
==============================================================================
Task         : Docker
Description  : Build or push Docker images, login or logout, start or stop containers, or run a Docker command
Version      : 2.214.0
Author       : Microsoft Corporation
Help         : https://aka.ms/azpipes-docker-tsg
==============================================================================
/usr/bin/docker images
/usr/bin/docker push nexus.XX.de/test:19899
REPOSITORY       TAG         IMAGE ID       CREATED        SIZE
<none>           <none>      bc4d269f1005   1 second ago   936MB
python           3.10        99199b67c562   12 hours ago   917MB
node             14          cc5014e36df3   5 days ago     916MB
node             16          5dd069ecb8d0   5 days ago     910MB
node             18          ee7f11c56c16   5 days ago     996MB
buildpack-deps   buster      cdc9ad60f652   5 days ago     803MB
buildpack-deps   bullseye    732382fed651   5 days ago     835MB
debian           10          ff5db168d4c5   5 days ago     114MB
debian           11          20473158e8b3   5 days ago     124MB
node             18-alpine   708a2a137388   6 days ago     174MB
ubuntu           20.04       e40cf56b4be3   8 days ago     72.8MB
moby/buildkit    latest      fb2b14fffd09   13 days ago    168MB
ubuntu           18.04       5d2df19066ac   2 weeks ago    63.1MB
ubuntu           22.04       58db3edaf2be   2 weeks ago    77.8MB
node             14-alpine   399cc5685cda   4 weeks ago    123MB
node             16-alpine   0e1140518c5f   4 weeks ago    118MB
alpine           3.16        bfe296a52501   2 months ago   5.54MB
alpine           3.14        dd53f409bf0b   6 months ago   5.6MB
alpine           3.15        c4fc93816858   6 months ago   5.58MB
The push refers to repository [nexus.XX.de/test]
An image does not exist locally with the tag: nexus.XX.de/test
##[error]An image does not exist locally with the tag: nexus.XX.de/test
##[error]The process '/usr/bin/docker' failed with exit code 1
Finishing: Push the image
```

My Pipeline:

```
trigger:
  none

resources:
- repo: self

variables:
  tag: '$(Build.BuildId)'

stages:
- stage: Build
  displayName: Build image
  jobs:
  - job: Build
    displayName: Build
    pool:
      vmImage: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
    - task: Docker@2
      displayName: logging in to the nexus repo
      inputs:
        containerRegistry: 'DockerTest'
        command: 'login'
    
    - task: Docker@2
      displayName: Build an image
      inputs:
        command: build
        dockerfile: '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)/Dockerfile'
        tags: $(tag)

      - task: Docker@2
      displayName: Push the image
      inputs:
        containerRegistry: 'DockerTest'
        repository: 'test'
        command: 'push'
        tags: |
          $(tag)
```

Is it conceptually correct to expect this to happen? What are the things to consider?

Comment: Where are you specifying the repository to use for the image you're building? I don't see you providing the `repository` parameter to `Docker@2`. What is the output of your `Docker@2` step?

Answer (score 0):

You're not specifying a `repository` parameter for the `Docker@2` build task, so the image isn't getting tagged. You can see this in the output you provided:

```
REPOSITORY       TAG         IMAGE ID       CREATED        SIZE
<none>           <none>      bc4d269f1005   1 second ago   936MB
```